# My blogger dropdown sub menu disappears on hover

Tags: drop-down-menu, hover, blogger

I just copies this code from a tutorial, But I try to open sub menu it disappears. I don't know what to do Please help me.

```
    #nav_wrapper1 {
    width: 100%;
    }
    .nav_wrapper {
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    position:top;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top .5s ease-out;
    background: #170030;
    height:60px;
    z-index:99999;
    }
    .btn {
    padding: 10px 1%;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: normal;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
    }
    .btn:hover {
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
    }
    #search i {color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;}
    #search {
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    line-height: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    #search:hover {
    background: #111;
    }
    .search_box {
    clear: both;
    width: 40%;
    background: #111;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    float:right;
    z-index:99999999999;
    }
    .search_box.active {
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width:40%;
    }
    .search_box input {
    width: 60%;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    }
    .search_box input:focus {
    outline: none;
    }
    .search_box input.search_icon {
    clear: both;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right:10px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #6a00de;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
    float:right;
    }
    .search_box input.search_icon:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    color:#111;
    }
    .menu-link {
    display: none;
    }
    .spinner-master input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
    }
    .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #170030;
    color:#170030;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    margin-top:5px;
    }
    .menu ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }
    .menu > li > ul.sub_menu {
    min-width: 10em;
    padding: 4px 0;
    background-color: #111;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .menu ul li {
    padding: 0px;
    }
    .menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    }
    .menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    height:100%;
    }
    .menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #111;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .menu ul li.hover > a {
    background: #111;
    color: #FFF;
    }
    .menu ul li > a {
    padding: 15px;
    }
    .menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    min-width: 160px;
    background: #111;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    }
    .menu ul ul > li {
    position: relative;
    }
    .menu ul ul > li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    height: auto;
    background: #000000;
    }
    .menu ul ul > li a:hover {
    background: #111;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 860px) {
    .example-header .container {
    width: 100%;
    }
    #search {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 5px;
    margin-top:25px;
    }
    .spinner-master * {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .spinner-master {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    }
    .spinner-master label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    }
    .spinner-master .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    }
    .spinner-master .diagonal.part-1 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    }
    .spinner-master .horizontal {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .spinner-master .diagonal.part-2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .horizontal {
    opacity: 0;
    }
    .spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .diagonal.part-1 {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .diagonal.part-2 {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -12px;
    }
    a.menu-link {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    a.menu-link:hover {
    color: #efa666;
    }
    a.menu-link:after {
    content: “2630”;
    font-weight: normal;
    }
    a.menu-link.active:after {
    content: “2715”;
    }
    .menu {
    clear: both;
    min-width: inherit;
    float: none;
      top:0px;
      position:relative;
    }
    .menu, .menu > ul ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    background-color: #39484d;
    }
    .menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none
    }
    .menu.active, .menu > ul ul.active {
    max-height: 55em;
    }
    .menu ul {
    display: inline;
    }
    .menu li, .menu > ul > li {
    display: block;
    }
    .menu > ul > li:last-of-type a {
    border: none;
    }
    .menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    }
    .menu li.has-submenu > a:after {`
    content: ‘+’;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.55em 0.5em;
    }
    .menu li.has-submenu > a.active:after {
    content: “-“;
    }
    .menu ul ul > li a {
    background:#170030;
    padding: 10px 18px 10px 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
    }
    .menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b5f65;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .menu ul li.hover > a {
    background: #111;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .menu ul ul, .menu ul ul ul {
    display: inherit;
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    border: none;
    }
    
    .search_box.active {
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;
    z-index: 10;
    width:70%;
      right:2px;
    }
    .search_box input {
    width: 50%;
      float:left;
    }
    .search_box input.search_icon {
    width: 30%;
      float:right;
      margin-right:14px;
      margin-top:-37px;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    min-width: 160px;
    background: #111;
    }
```

delete ***display: none***

```
.menu ul ul {
      
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        min-width: 160px;
        background: #111;
        }
```

or change to **display:block;**

```
.menu ul ul {
        display:block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        min-width: 160px;
        background: #111;
        }
```

try it..